# Fix header above body tag in a simple div

Tags: html

I have a simple div tag:
I need to make the thead fixed and above the tbody.
I need to have them within the same div, same table.
With the below code, my header is over the body. How Can I push the tbody down a few notches, so when i scroll the header is fixed and only the body moves

```
<div STYLE=" height: 120px; width: 100px; font-size: 12px; overflow: auto;">
  <table bgcolor="green">
    <thead style="position:fixed;">
        <tr><td bgcolor="#fafafa">hello</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
   <tr><td bgcolor="#dadada">www.hioxindia.com</td></tr>
   <tr><td >maths.hscripts.com</td></tr>
   <tr><td bgcolor="#dadada">www.hscripts.com</td></tr>
   <tr><td>free php scripts</td></tr>
   <tr><td bgcolor="#dadada">www.hiox4u.com</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Has to work on IE
For the above div... I need to add scroll with fixed header on top of the table. No additional divs or table should be included inbetween. I need the thead and tbody to be within the same table

Comment: Why do you need it in the same table?  Sometimes you need to think outside the box in order to get things to work like you want.  You can make this behave like you want if you break out the header.  It can be inside the same div.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: For the above div... I need to add scroll with fixed header on top of the table. No additional divs or table should be included inbetween. I need the thead and tbody to be within the same table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code as a basis, here is a jsfiddle I've tested in Chrome and IE10 and it works there at least.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YbQzF/

code:

```
<div STYLE=" height: 120px; width: 100px; font-size: 12px; overflow: auto;">
  <table bgcolor="green">
    <thead style="position: fixed">
        <tr><td bgcolor="#fafafa">hello</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="overflow:scroll; max-height:100px; position:absolute; top:20px;">
   <tr><td bgcolor="#dadada">www.hioxindia.com</td></tr>
   <tr><td >maths.hscripts.com</td></tr>
   <tr><td bgcolor="#dadada">www.hscripts.com</td></tr>
   <tr><td>free php scripts</td></tr>
   <tr><td bgcolor="#dadada">www.hiox4u.com</td></tr>
   <tr><td>free php scripts</td></tr>
   <tr><td bgcolor="#dadada">www.hiox4u.com</td></tr>
   <tr><td>free php scripts</td></tr>
   <tr><td bgcolor="#dadada">www.hiox4u.com</td></tr>
...
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>​
```

Comment: @Haran Murthy have you tried this solution?  Is there some way in which this does not solve the problem you have?  Per my testing it works in the browsers in question, does not introduce new divs or tables and uses rather standard css stylings.

Answer (score 0):

```
table { margin-top:-3em; }
thead { margin-top:-2em; }
```

Works in FF and Chrome on my computer. It's hideous and hacky and I do not approve this message, but it works.